# Notation for algebraic tangles

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

The Conway notation for rational knots is well known. I could use one for the more general algebraic tangles. As the name already says, one could build one out of tangle addition $+$, multiplication $*$, and the simple tangles over- and undercrossing ($o,u$). More elegant would be multiplication, 90° rotation ($r()$) and overcrossing, you would only need three symbols, one for the overcrossing and two for bracketing. Note that I assume mutations are equal: $r(r(t))=t$ for any tangle $t$.

The real problem is that I would also need a complete set of rules telling me if two tangles are the same (modulo Reidemeister moves), ideally by rewriting any tangle formula in some minimal canonic form (defined whatever way). For example (symbolically) for any tangle $t$, $(t*o+u)*o=r(t)$, i.e. you can rotate a tangle with three additional crossings. Note e.g. also $(u*u+u*u)*o=(u+u)*(o+o)+o$ and it's not obvious which version should be declared canonic (or even if always the one with the least number of crossings should be canonic - the Borromei rings with one crossing cut out, i.e. five crossings, is an algebraic tangle, but seven crossings are needed to make it from $\{u,o,+,*\}$).

Surely such a system already exists?